# New RAID array will not auto assemble, leads to boot problems

Tags: raid, mdadm

I had just asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210307/boot-failure-no-errors-but-i-cant-access-the-shell) where I was unable to boot after installing a new RAID1 Array. I was able to get to the terminal, but once I sorted that out I realized that my problem isn't so much an fstab boot problem as an mdadm auto assemble problem.

I have three RAID1 arrays on my system, with `/dev/md1` mounted at `/` and `/dev/md0` mounted as `swap`, and these currently run without problems. I did not create these arrays. I created a new RAID1 array, `/dev/md2` which I formatted to ext4 using [this guide](http://ewams.net/?view=Formatting_a_RAID_volume_with_ext4), and in doing so I created a new partition (the only one) as `md2p1` (the guide also created a similarly named partition although fdisk never explicitly asked for a name).

Upon creating this new array I was able to mount manually using

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/md2p1 /srv/Waveforms
```

And this worked fine. I was able to access the directory and added about 700 GB worth of data to it. After doing this, I get

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdd1[1]
      1953423552 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      961136576 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      15624128 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

, so the computer clearly recognizes the array. I then used

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

and the file now contains

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=afa7ccee:df4dfa79:a84dbc05:35401226
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=a0c526cc:6de93504:c8b94301:85474c49
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=1ac720e1:192b2c38:f6e0357b:f3e0074f

# This file was auto-generated on Thu, 10 Mar 2011 00:57:55 -0700
# by mkconf $Id$
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=afa7ccee:df4dfa79:a84dbc05:35401226
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=a0c526cc:6de93504:c8b94301:85474c49
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=1ac720e1:192b2c38:f6e0357b:f3e0074f
```

Two things to note here. The original file had `metadata=00.90`, but I modified this to be `metadata=0.90` as this solved a minor issue where the metadata was not recognized (a quick google search will explain this).

The second think to note is that auto is set to yes, meaning that the system should automatically assemble all the arrays on boot. This must be the case, as the fact that I am able to boot at all must mean that /dev/md1 has been assembled.

Anyways, now the trouble. Upon reboot, my machine hangs and tells me

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/md1: clean, 3680768/60071936 files, 208210802/240284144 blocks
```

My fstab currently reads

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/md1 during installation
UUID=1d3cb392-f522-485b-8516-a7791fc23c4d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=6eb8e6f2-3166-4f77-883c-26268d636b0b none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/md2p1 /srv/Waveforms            ext4    defaults,noauto              0       0
```

with

```
blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="afa7ccee-df4d-fa79-a84d-bc0535401226" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="a0c526cc-6de9-3504-c8b9-430185474c49" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="afa7ccee-df4d-fa79-a84d-bc0535401226" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="a0c526cc-6de9-3504-c8b9-430185474c49" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="1ac720e1-192b-2c38-f6e0-357bf3e0074f" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="1ac720e1-192b-2c38-f6e0-357bf3e0074f" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0: UUID="6eb8e6f2-3166-4f77-883c-26268d636b0b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/md1: UUID="1d3cb392-f522-485b-8516-a7791fc23c4d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/md2p1: UUID="867ee91e-527e-435b-b6bc-2f6d89d2d8c6" TYPE="ext4"
```

I had previously used `UUID=867ee91e-527e-435b-b6bc-2f6d89d2d8c6` in lieu of `/dev/md2p1`, but that gave me no results. I have also tried options as defaults, defaults+noatime,errors=remount-ro with this md2p1, but none worked.

I am able to boot by modifying fstab to exclude my new md2p1 line. After boot with this configuration, I get

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      15624128 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      961136576 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

So the system has not assembled md2. I can then run

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
[sudo] password for zach: 
mdadm: /dev/md2 has been started with 2 drives.
```

whence

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdd1[1]
      1953423552 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      15624128 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      961136576 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

and I can now manually mount as above. So the problem seems to be that the RAID1 array is not assembling on boot, and thus is not recognized by fstab, and thus I cannot boot at all except in a recovery mode.

I've found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/287462/how-can-i-make-mdadm-auto-assemble-raid-after-each-boot) post, but I don't think it applies to me, as the answer seems to be to set auto to yes, which then automatically assembles the arrays on boot. My configuration is already set to do this, so I'm at a loss.

There is an answer in that post that does seem applicable, but I don't understand what his solution was. This is the post by Deplicator, which says

> After a reboot I could never see /dev/md0. Running the mdadm --detail
>   --scan again (without putting the result in a file) I would see
>
> ```
> ARRAY /dev/md/ubuntu:0 metadata=1.2 name=ubuntu:0 UUID=a8a570c6:96f61865:05abe131:5c2e2f7e
> ```
>
> and manually mounting /dev/md/ubuntu:0 would work. In the end, that
>   was what I put in the fstab file too.

What was put into fstab? The problem seems to be that I am not assembling md2 on boot, and thus I will hang every time fstab tries to mount the md2p1 partition. This may in fact be related to md2 being partitioned while the others are not, but I fail to see why this should be the case.

Edit: Just in case

```
uname -a
Linux ccldas2 2.6.32-74-server #142-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 28 10:12:19 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two issues spring to mind

1. You've got duplicate array definitions in `mdadm.conf`. Replace (or comment out) the block of three `ARRAY` lines following `# definitions of existing MD arrays` so that each array is declared only by your most recent scan.
2. A typical scenario for RAID arrays that fail to build on boot is that either they have not been updated in the `initramfs` or they are not set to run at boot time. A really quick scan through [the guide you referenced](http://ewams.net/?view=Formatting_a_RAID_volume_with_ext4) doesn't appear to mention these steps, but I could be wrong. On Debian systems the commands are:

   ```
    dpkg-reconfigure mdadm    # Choose "all" disks to start at boot
    update-initramfs -u       # Updates the existing initramfs
   ```

Comment: roaima, I am forever in your debt. I may now go to sleep. I shall sing to my children of your wisdom.

For those following along, I also updated mdadm before I did this, and that may or may not have had an effect. I would recommend trying this first, and then updating mdadm if it doesn't work, just because updating mdadm also required updating a hundred other things, which created yet more problems. 

In all seriousness, though. Thanks. You've solved not only this problem, but another.

Comment: roaima I wanted to thank you. Mine was due to issue 1 where I had duplicate information in my mdadm.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

In the `mdadm.conf` you only need the UUID, like so

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=d8b8b4e5:e47b2e45:2093cd36:f654020d
```

All other conditions can prevent the RAID from being assembled.

For (deprecated) auto assembly, you need:

- partition type `fd`
- metadata `0.90`
- either no initramfs at all, or make sure the initramfs does `raidautorun /dev/disk`

If auto assembly fails, `dmesg` should hold some pointers as to what went wrong.

In general, if possible (and if initramfs is involved anyway) you should stick to the newer default `1.2` metadata format and have an initramfs with `mdadm`, `mdadm.conf` set up.