# Linux raid disappears after reboot

Tags: linux, raid

My troubleshooting ability in Linux is not impressive, just so you know. I can follow instructions very well on the other hand. I have a Linux server with Linux raid. It was working well with no problems for about half a year but then I had a power failure and have been getting the same problem ever since. After rebuilding the raid all my files are still there, so that's a good thing. When I reboot the server the raid device md0 is gone.

```
pi@pinas:~ $ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>

pi@pinas:~ $ ls /dev/md*
pi@pinas:~ $
```

I found an [issue here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1223457) that seems to have helped other people but I tried it and it did not help. I also looked at several other sites all saying the similar things. I use webmin to create the raid and the mdadm.conf "looks" ok. I don't know if I am searching the internet for the right things or even if I am looking in the right log files. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in adavance.

***Edit 1

```
root@pinas:/home/pi# service mdadm start
Failed to start mdadm.service: Unit mdadm.service is masked.
```

I am wondering if the mdadm service is even running. The process is not currently active on the system and I have no idea how to tell if it is configured to start on boot, how to start it or configure it to start on boot.

***Edit 2

```
systemctl list-unit-files
mdadm-grow-continue@.service           static  
mdadm-last-resort@.service             static  
mdadm-waitidle.service                 masked  
mdadm.service                          masked  
mdmon@.service                         static  
mdmonitor.service                      static
```

I found this. I don't know exactly if this is bad but it is suspicious looking. Is this how it should be? None of them say enabled and I would think they should. Any Ideas?

***Edit 3

```
systemctl list-unit-files
mdadm-grow-continue@.service           static  
mdadm-last-resort@.service             static  
mdadm-waitidle.service                 masked  
mdadm.service                          masked  
mdmon@.service                         static  
mdmonitor.service                      static  

dpkg-reconfigure mdadm
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u3) ...
```

I ran the commands that @telcoM suggested and this is the output. I also tried doing a reinstall then those commands, but still the output is the same.

I have tried looking at several other similarly named treads on the net but so far I have not found anything that seems helpful. I think the problem is related to the service not starting on boot but I am not experienced enough with Linux services to know how to fix it. @roaima suggested that it was a problem with initramfs but I do not know how to check or correct that. Does anyone have any ideas?

***Edit 4

```
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes
HOMEHOST <system>
MAILADDR root
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=d3434dfc:2fb4792e:0b64f806:67e35ee3 name=raspberrypi:0
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=40fb937f:870c7c13:46774666:87445bc5 name=pinas:0
```

Here is the out put of my mdadm.conf file. which is interesting because the first listed array does not have the right name...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New RAID array will not auto assemble, leads to boot problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/new-raid-array-will-not-auto-assemble-leads-to-boot-problems)

Comment: @telcoM Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using raspbian.

Comment: @roaima I read that one it does not seem to be the same, but maybe it is and I just don't know any better.

Comment: Check the creation of initramfs, as described in the possible duplicate. If there's no RAID on boot this is a strong possibility.

Comment: @roaima I'm not sure how to check the initramfs, but I did run the commands from the referenced link.

Comment: @roaima would you mind removing the duplicate tag since it does not seem to be a duplicate?

Comment: Please provide the non-comment lines from your mdadm.conf. Also, before running the commands in the linked answer you must have your RAID array running and the mdadm.conf file correct. Otherwise the initramfs will (still) contain invalid information.

Comment: I haven't yet seen any evidence that this  isn't a duplicate, but ultimately it's not my call on what the community thinks.

Comment: @roaima I have attached the output from the mdadm.conf file, I also tried commenting out the other array line but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service was not starting because it was masked. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804946/systemctl-how-to-unmask) is how I found how to unmask it. the next problem was the mdadm-raid service was not starting the raid. [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47312) was how I got the raid to start on boot. Look down to "Mon Jul 31, 2017 7:49 pm" to find the relevant post. This may not be the best solution but after 10 reboots the raid is still starting every time. I do appreciate the efforts from the people who have tried to answer this thread. Now I just need to sort out the other services provided. but that is a problem for another day.

Comment: Please post the relevant information in your answer.  Include the links for reference and attribution.

Answer (score 13):

This recipe worked for me after having the same issue. Looked all over the net trying to find the answer, and finally coming across this, and still no help.

The problem as I see it is multifold.

1. mdadm reassigns the device files from `/dev/md0` to something like `/dev/md127` on the next reboot.  So you cannot just use the device file in the fstab.  I ended up using the UUID, from the created filesystem.
2. Almost all the RAID drive setup tutorials on the web are showing the creation of the RAID device using the driver device files like this:

   ```
   mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
   ```

   Instead I used the partition device files, like this:

   ```
   mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
   ```

   The second form requires proper creation of partitions on each disk using `gdisk` or `fdisk`. I used `gdisk` and assigned it as type `fd00`, which is a raid partition.
3. There's lots of talk about needing to update `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`.  This is wrong. I purposefully, deleted that file. It's not needed. (See below)

That's really all there is too it.  Full recipe follows...

---

Partition each drive with one partition of type `fd00`, Linux RAID:

```
root@teamelchan:~# gdisk /dev/sda
Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1):
First sector (2048-3907029134, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:
Last sector (2048-3907029134, default = 3907029134) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): fd00
Changed type of partition to 'Linux RAID'

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model: ST2000DM001-1ER1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F81E265F-2D02-864D-AF62-CEA1471CFF39
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 2048, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number Start (sector) End (sector) Size Code Name
1
2048 3907029134 1.8 TiB FD00 Linux RAID

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sda.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

Now you should see both the disk devices and partition devices in /dev

```
root@teamelchan:~# ls /dev/sd[a-d]*
/dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd /dev/sdd1
```

Now create the RAID of your choice with mdadm using the partition device files, not the disk devices

```
root@teamelchan:~# mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
size=471724032K mtime=Sun Nov 18 19:42:02 2018
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Thu Nov 22 04:00:11 2018
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Thu Nov 22 04:00:11 2018
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Thu Nov 22 04:00:11 2018
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
size=2930265540K mtime=Sun Nov 18 23:58:02 2018
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 appears to be part of a raid array:
level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Thu Nov 22 04:00:11 2018
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

Now check in `/dev/disk` to see if there's any UUID associated with your new `/dev/md0` RAID.
There should be none.

```
root@teamelchan:~# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 04:24 4777-FB10 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 04:24 D616BDCE16BDAFBB -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 04:24 e79571b6-eb75-11e8-acb0-e0d55e117fa5 -> ../../sdf2
```

Make the new filesystem, and after that you should now have a UUID with `/dev/md0`

```
root@teamelchan:~# mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Creating filesystem with 2685945088 4k blocks and 335745024 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 7bd945b4-ded9-4ef0-a075-be4c7ea246fb
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632,
2560000000

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Voila, there it is.

```
root@teamelchan:~# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 04:24 4777-FB10 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 22 04:43 7bd945b4-ded9-4ef0-a075-be4c7ea246fb -> ../../md0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 04:24 D616BDCE16BDAFBB -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 04:24 e79571b6-eb75-11e8-acb0-e0d55e117fa5 -> ../../sdf2
```

Modify your /etc/fstab and add the mount for your new RAID
Be sure to use the UUID, and not the device file.

```
root@teamelchan:~# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=e79571b6-eb75-11e8-acb0-e0d55e117fa5 / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=4777-FB10 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0
/swap.img none
swap sw 0 0
UUID=7bd945b4-ded9-4ef0-a075-be4c7ea246fb /md0/tweets ext4 auto 0 0
```

Here, look no `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
It's not needed.

```
root@teamelchan:~# ls -l /etc/mdadm
total 0
```

Reboot

```
root@teamelchan:~# reboot
Connection to 192.168.0.131 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.0.131 closed.
```

The RAID is mounted, but mdadm has renamed the device file from `md0` to `md127`

#### Good thing we used the UUID and not the actual device file.

```
root@teamelchan:~# df /md0/tweets
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md127 10658016696 73660 10120737636 1% /md0/tweets
```

Look md0 is gone from /dev

```
root@teamelchan:~# ls /dev/md*
/dev/md127

/dev/md:
```

That's it. Now I'm enjoying my 10 Terabyte RAID0 that operates at over 600 MB/sec

```
root@teamelchan:~# hdparm -tT /dev/md127

/dev/md127:
Timing cached reads: 26176 MB in 1.99 seconds = 13137.47 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 1878 MB in 3.00 seconds = 625.13 MB/sec
```

Comment: 1. The subunit (127 from your /dev/md127) is stored in the array metadata. It can be changed with mdadm. 2. You used to need the mdadm.conf if you're booting with an initramfs. (I don't think it's needed on systems like a Pi because they don't use initramfs.)

Comment: @roaima This recipe is not specific to Pi. I'm doing this on Linux 18.04 Server LTS, on a regular PC. I've also tried the initramfs suggested solution, which also doesn't work. So at least in Linux 18.04 Server LTS the 'mdadm' does not require /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file.

Comment: After trawling through posts, this is the answer that finally did it for me.  The first time I tried to set up the array with disc partitions it failed though so I’m not entirely sure what I did differently.  It’s possible that using the UUID for my fstab is what did the trick.

Comment: Upvoted, this one actually works. Of all the tutorials on the net, only one works, a little sad actually. Thank you for posting this solution!

Answer (score 3):

Your `/proc/mdstat` indicates that none of the RAID personalities (i.e. RAID1, RAID5, etc.) have been loaded, so no attempt is made to even try activating a RAID set.

```
Failed to start mdadm.service: Unit mdadm.service is masked.
```

This message indicates `mdadm.service` has been disabled in the strongest possible way: no explicit attempt will be made to start the service, and even if something else depends on this service, it won't be started.

As in the [question linked by roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/new-raid-array-will-not-auto-assemble-leads-to-boot-problems), try running these commands as root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure mdadm    # Choose "all" disks to start at boot
update-initramfs -u       # Updates the existing initramfs
```

The first will reconfigure the `mdadm` package and should detect all the RAID sets and let you choose which RAID sets to auto-activate at boot: usually "all" is a good answer. This should also take care of the `mdadm.service` being masked, if I've understood correctly.

Once that is done, the second command will update your initramfs, so that the updated configuration files will be updated in your initramfs too, and the scripts that will be executed in the earliest phases of boot will get the information that there is a RAID set that should be activated.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that did not work. I will edit my post to show the new output.

Comment: Did the `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` command pop any question dialogs at all?

Comment: yes, the first one explains whats going on, the second asks for all,  the third asks if mdadm should run monthly checks, the forth asks to start the md monitoring service to send emails, fifth asks what user to email. It then displays the two warnings and done.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is that you have two definitions for the same RAID device `/dev/md/0` in your `mdadm conf`. You need to fix that first.

Then get your array running, and finally you can follow the instructions at [New RAID array will not auto assemble, leads to boot problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/new-raid-array-will-not-auto-assemble-leads-to-boot-problems) -

```
dpkg-reconfigure mdadm # Choose "all" disks to start at boot
update-initramfs -u # Updates the existing initramfs
```

Comment: Good morning, I commented out the the two old lines. Re-created the the array. Mounted it. Verified that my files were still there. The array is happy and working. I ran the two commands got the same warnings already posted. Rebooted and the array was gone. The services are still not starting on boot. I don't know how big of a problem that is, though.

Comment: @Goff Hmm. I'll see if I can reproduce this on my Pi.