# mdadm RAID array disappered after reboot

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, raid, disk, manjaro

I'm running manjaro and I just set up an additional RAID 0 using mdadm and formatted it as ext4. I started using it and everything worked great. After I rebooted however, the array has disappeared. I figured it just hasn't automatically reassembled itself, but it appears to have completely disappeared:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/nvme0 /dev/nvme1 /dev/nvme2
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/nvme0: Invalid argument
mdadm: /dev/nvme0 has no superblock - assembly aborted

cat /proc/mdstat
cat: /proc/mdstat: No such file or directory

cat /etc/mdstat/mdstat.conf
cat: /etc/mdstat/mdstat.conf: No such file or directory

sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --force
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

So it appears even the config of that Array has disappeared? *And* the superblocks? Now for the moment let's assume the drives didn't randomly fail during the reboot, even though that isn't impossible. I didn't store any crucial data on that array of course, but I have to understand where things went wrong. Of course, recovering the array would be great and could save me a few hours of setting things up.

Some extra information

```
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1"
```

The disks should be using GPT though, as far as I remember. Is there some param I need to set for it to try using GPT?

I since found out that recreating the array without formatting will restore access to all data on it:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose --level=0 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=3 /dev/md/hpa /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1
```

but every time I reboot it disappears again and I have to recreate it.

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/hpa metadata=1.2 name=Mnemosyne:hpa UUID=02f959b6:f432e82a:108e8b0d:8df6f2bf

cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] 
md127 : active raid0 nvme2n1[2] nvme1n1[1] nvme0n1[0]
        1464763392 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

What else could I try to analyze this issue?

Comment: Have you got your `mdadm --detail --scan` output in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`?

Comment: Yes. I just discovered that the issue may be that I am creating the array on partitions rather than directly on the block device, however if I try to create it directly: sudo mdadm --create --verbose --level=0 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=3 /dev/md/hpa /dev/nvme0 /dev/nvme1 /dev/nvme2 
it tells me that this isn't a block device.

Comment: May be related to this nvme quirk: https://serverfault.com/questions/892134/why-is-there-both-character-device-and-block-device-for-nvme
Will try this method next and report back here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411286/linux-raid-disappears-after-reboot

Comment: This fixed it. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the solution that worked for me was to format my nvme drives with a single fd00 linux raid partition, and then using that for the RAID.

```
gdisk /dev/nvme[0-2]n1
```

Command n, then press enter until prompted for a Hex code partition type. Enter fd00, press enter. Command w and confirm.
Repeat this for all drives, then proceed to create your array as before, but this time use the partitions you created insted of the block device, for example:

```
mdadm --create --verbose --level=0 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=3 /dev/md/hpa /dev/nvme0n1p1 /dev/nvme1n1p1 /dev/nvme2n1p1
```