# Missing drive in software RAID array after reboot

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have the Problem that I made a software RAID6-array of 6 HDD's. However, everytime the system gets rebooted the Array becomes inactive and after starting it again it degenerates, were always the same drive is missing (`/dev/sde`). When I re-add the drive the array reassembles and functions properly again, but I'd like to solve that problem.

Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Drives (x6)

```
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD100EFAX-68LHPN0
Firmware Version: 83.H0A83
User Capacity:    10.000.831.348.736 bytes [10,0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Apr 20 22:45:13 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` (after reboot):

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sdc[2](S) sdf[5](S) sdd[3](S) sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      48831523840 blocks super 1.2
```

`mdadm --detail /dev/md0` (after re-adding `/dev/sde`)

```
               Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Aug 12 20:25:02 2020
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 39065219072 (37255.50 GiB 40002.78 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 9766304768 (9313.87 GiB 10000.70 GB)
      Raid Devices : 6
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Apr 14 14:20:42 2021
             State : clean, degraded, recovering
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 6
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Rebuild Status : 13% complete

              Name : 
              UUID : c41002b3:537a96c4:d6a3e2a9:f6debd2b
            Events : 87437

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       2       8       32        2      active sync   /dev/sdc
       3       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd
       6       8       64        4      spare rebuilding   /dev/sde
       5       8       80        5      active sync   /dev/sdf
```

`mdadm --detail /dev/md0` (after reassembly)

```
    /dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Aug 12 20:25:02 2020
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 39065219072 (37255.50 GiB 40002.78 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 9766304768 (9313.87 GiB 10000.70 GB)
      Raid Devices : 6
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Mar 10 14:08:55 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 6
   Working Devices : 6
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name :
              UUID : c41002b3:537a96c4:d6a3e2a9:f6debd2b
            Events : 72271


    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       2       8       32        2      active sync   /dev/sdc
       3       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd
       6       8       64        4      active sync   /dev/sde
       5       8       80        5      active sync   /dev/sdf
```

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=50ba9118-24c0-4483-bc27-6e8d2fc3b844 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=F92D-03DC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0


#Mount RAID-Array (last edit: 16/04/2021; lukas)
#/dev/md0 /mnt/md1 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
#UUID= 29994073-b1c9-4b0f-8168-77c2475d6133
UUID=29994073-b1c9-4b0f-8168-77c2475d6133 /mnt/md1 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Boot-Log
It appears the RAID device times out.

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device 3-b1c9-4b0f-8168-77c2475d6133.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/md1.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting Create final runt…dir for shutdown pivot root...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[  OK  ] Finished Create final runt…e dir for shutdown pivot root.
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Have the logs anything to say about `/dev/sde` or `md0` (in relation to the boot process)? Could `/dev/sde` possibly be detected too late, after the array has been assembled? E.g. are all the six disks attached to the same controller?

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. This is my first time really working in depth with a Linux system. Could you please guide me, where I could find this files/info so that I can provide it here?

Comment: What operating system are you using? The location of logs depends on that, among other things. Some information on your hardware may also be useful: what kind of system is it? Are your disks SATA/SCSI/USB/...? All of the same kind?

Comment: Hey,Sorry for the delayed info -> all drives are of the same kind and I edited my original post to include drive information as well as OS info

Comment: Hello, I restarted the server for the first time since the start of my post and now included a boot-log as my problem seems to persist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New RAID array will not auto assemble, leads to boot problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/new-raid-array-will-not-auto-assemble-leads-to-boot-problems)