# is the mdadm configuration ok?

Tags: linux, centos, raid, mdadm

I have installed a new raid 10 under `/dev/md123` and I want to be sure that the raid array is ok after reboot.

my original mdadm.config was

```
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
MAILADDR root
AUTO +imsm +1.x -all
ARRAY /dev/md/boot level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=fd36f8a9:d02a1229:c11a8feb:ac529491
ARRAY /dev/md/home level=raid10 num-devices=4 UUID=5d619c21:250f4f48:2bfe1c59:0d832a9d
ARRAY /dev/md/root level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=ca8c432a:beca45c5:cd4ecca3:91723196
ARRAY /dev/md/swap level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=6a86f000:9ce02893:6f27b781:d3815dcd
```

After I ran `mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm.conf` i got this

```
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
MAILADDR root
AUTO +imsm +1.x -all
ARRAY /dev/md/boot level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=fd36f8a9:d02a1229:c11a8feb:ac529491
ARRAY /dev/md/home level=raid10 num-devices=4 UUID=5d619c21:250f4f48:2bfe1c59:0d832a9d
ARRAY /dev/md/root level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=ca8c432a:beca45c5:cd4ecca3:91723196
ARRAY /dev/md/swap level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=6a86f000:9ce02893:6f27b781:d3815dcd
ARRAY /dev/md/swap level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=server7.host.net:swap UUID=6a86f000:9ce02893:6f27b781:d3815dcd
   devices=/dev/sda2,/dev/sdb2
ARRAY /dev/md/boot level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=server7.host.net:boot UUID=fd36f8a9:d02a1229:c11a8feb:ac529491
   devices=/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3
ARRAY /dev/md/root level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=server7.host.net:root UUID=ca8c432a:beca45c5:cd4ecca3:91723196
   devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1
ARRAY /dev/md/home level=raid10 num-devices=4 metadata=1.2 name=server7.host.net:home UUID=5d619c21:250f4f48:2bfe1c59:0d832a9d
   devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1,/dev/sde1,/dev/sdf1
ARRAY /dev/md123 level=raid10 num-devices=4 metadata=1.2 name=server7.host.net:123 UUID=dc18bc08:d162b25f:b7ef3fc7:62e0542d
   devices=/dev/sdg1,/dev/sdh1,/dev/sdi1,/dev/sdj1
```

Is the `mdadm.config` ok or should I removed the duplicated rows for `/home` `/boot` `/swap`

Comment: I'd say that's definitely not ok. You should only have one ARRAY entry per md device. See a related answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210421/100397

Comment: It's way too verbose, reduce to `ARRAY /dev/mdX UUID=y`.